# Is there a way to reference variable name as a string in that variable's declaration in Python?

Tags: python, django

For my Django application, I have a dictionary of field names (keys) mapped to help texts (values) (which I read in from a csv file). In `models.py`, I want to retrieve the appropriate help text for each field name.

If I have a sample dictionary like the following, with an entry for each field:

```
test_dict = {
    'host_name': 'The name of a host',
     ...
}
```

And my `models.py` looks like this:

```
class Host_main(models.Model):

    host_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, help_text=test_dict['host_name'])
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.host_name
```

Is there a way to call the variable name (`host_name`) dynamically in each `help_text` definition?

I do have the option to do something like the following:

```
from varname import nameof
host_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, help_text=test_dict[nameof(host_name)])
```

But if possible, I'd like to reference the current variable name with something consistent to avoid typing out the field name a second time, like `help_text=test_dict[nameof(**this**)]` in pseudocode.

Thanks!

Comment: If you provide a variable like `host_name_key = 'host_name'`, you can use that `help_text=test_dict[host_name_key]`, but I'm not sure whether I understood what you want to achieve here.

Comment: Unless you mean that you want to use that field name from `host_name = models.CharField(...)`. If so, it could be possible, but you would need to have somewhere code which iterate through a`Host_main` class attributes, and changes their `help_text`. Doable most likely, but seems like overkill.

Comment: Thanks, the idea is more that since I have to do this for every single field in my Django app database (144 fields), I'd like the declaration for each to be the same, I.e. `help_text = test_dict[<this>]` with <this> being a generic way of referring to whatever the field name is

Comment: Just saw your second comment..yes, that would be good. My dictionary holds all 144 fields (for all the classes), so ideally I could iterate through all the classes in one loop

Answer (score 2):

Let's simplify your question a little bit, and let's remove the django part first. Let's say you have a class with name `A`, then you can set an attribute on `A` with

```py
class A: pass

A.foo = 'bar'
```

Alternatively, you can also do

```py
setattr(A,'bar','baz')
```

You can verify that those are indeed equivalent by checking

```py
print(A.foo) # bar
print(A.bar) # baz
```

So if you are defining a normal class, you can pretty much just loop through your `dict` and set things with `setattr` calls, in which case you have the control of the variable name.

And when we bring Django into the question, things are a bit more complicated...There are some very [strange and magical](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e48e78738e224a056df57b7cb08bd48ac0e54f60/django/db/models/base.py#L74) things happening when you initialize a `Model` class. Basically it does a lookup on things already defined, and transforms all the defined fields through the pretty much public private `_meta` API. This means that adding class attributes outside of definition time won't work, and you might have to use a bit of a hack to construct a class directly through its metaclass (in case you are not familiar with Python's metaclasses, a class is basically an instance of its metaclass).

The basic syntax for dynamically constructing a class is through the `type` call with 3 arguments: `type(name, bases, dict)`. In your example,

```py
class Host_main(models.Model):

    host_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, help_text=test_dict['host_name'])
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.host_name
```

is the equivalent of

```py
def Host_main_str(self): # the name here doesn't really matter unless you care about the __name__ attribute of the function, which you can overwrite.
    return self.host_name

Host_main = type('Host_main', (models.Model,), {
        '__str__': Host_main_str,
        'host_name': models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, help_text=test_dict['host_name'])
    })
```

It's actually [how](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7cba92ec55a5d05450261f375830619870ca84fa/django/db/models/utils.py#L42) django constructs all their QuerySet classes (there were some more crazy things django did with dynamic class constructions if I remember correctly but I couldn't find a good example)

So, you can do things like

```py
attr_dict = {'__str__':'Host_main_str'}
for name, help_text in test_dict.values():
    attr_dict[name] = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, help_text=help_text)

Host_main = type('Host_main', (models.Model,), attr_dict)
```

if you really insist on loop through a dictionary.

Comment: That is really an awesome answer.